# System error: null argument to internal routine in xmlsec

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, system, xmlsec

I am trying to implement SSO in a Django application. I have a ubuntu 16.04 OS, Apache and WSGI and python 3.5.2
The packages that I installed:

```
xlmsec 1.3.3
lxml 4.5.1
pkg-config 1.5.1
python3-saml 1.9.0
```

And all the dependencies for xmlsec: libxmlsec1-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-openssl

My server is behind a proxy (I dont have full access to that server) trying to install xlmsec >= 1.3.7 throws me a connection error, that why I used 1.3.3 version.

Once I run the following command I get the error:

```
python -c "import xmlsec"
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyLoadMemory:file=app.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=data != NULL:error=100:assertion:
func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=185:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=exact;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=30;real subminor version=20
func=xmlSecOpenSSLInit:file=crypto.c:line=312:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecCheckVersionExact:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:
func=xmlSecOpenSSLAppPkcs12Load:file=app.c:line=580:obj=unknown:subj=filename != NULL:error=100:assertion:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: null argument to internal routine
```

I am not sure if it could be something about wrong versions or related to xlmsec issue (I already tried to rollback to older versions and have the same issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a libxmlsec1 (ubuntu package) version installed (version was 1.2.20 and xmlsec needs 1.2.30). Just remove the older version and installed the new one.